# How to stop urlRequest onViewDisappear

Tags: swift

I load my json info from my server as follows, but when I click away to a different page too soon, the request keeps trying in the background and there is a warning that the viewController can't be found anymore. How would I cancel all requests onViewDisappear?

```
if let requestURL = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/file.php") {

        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "email=\(loginUsername.text!)"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) {  (data, response, error) in

            if let data = data {
                do {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {

                        // Async Stuff
                        DispatchQueue.main.async{

                            // do things
                        }

                        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        })
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: `task.cancel()` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `cancel` for the task, but the `сompletionHandler` will still be called. You must use a weak reference for the controller.

```
let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest as URLRequest) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
    self?.doSomeThing()
}
```